# Yarn/NPM doesnt install all packages

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, yarnpkg

On my AWS machine I have an Angular 2 web app created with `@angular/cli`. I've tried to install all packages with `yarn`/`npm` but it doesn't seem to install everything, because when I enter to the website it doesn't inject any provider and it doesn't render properly.

I've deleted the whole folder of `node_modules/` `.npm/cache` `yarn/cache` reinstalled everything with `yarn` and `npm` but it doesn't work either.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "seon.site-builder.ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.24",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^0.0.3",
    "angular2-esri-loader": "^0.1.11",
    "angular2-esri4-components": "^0.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "esri-loader": "^0.1.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-signalr": "1.0.8",
    "ng2-table": "^1.3.2",
    "ng2-validation": "^3.8.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^4.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "settings-editor": "0.0.11",
    "signalr": "^2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.11",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.32.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/arcgis-js-api": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.58",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

> Node: 6.10.2
>
> Npm: 3.10.10
>
> Yarn: 0.22.0

After running:

```
npm cache clean
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

I'll get `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` errors with Angular:

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.10
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.10
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.10
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.4.10
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@5.1.0
```

Comment: is `npm serve` is actually working after all? It is sounds like one of your npm modules required these versions but that might be not a problem if you are using any newer angualar version. You can find out what is referencing these and try to update that particular package.